# How to convert a multi-indexed dataframe, a dataframe grouped by multi columns to nested json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My Pandas Series, which I got from applying groupby operation on DataFrame with columns 'var' and 'month' and applying sum on the corresponding data looks like this ('var' and 'month' are indexes below) :

```
    var  month
X   Feb     -0.061575
    Jan      1.366478
Y   Feb     -1.310896
Z   Apr      0.053076
    Feb      1.292415
    Mar      0.375144
P   Feb      1.241288
    Mar      0.613453
```

What I want a format of JSON created from the above DataFrame like below:

```
'data':[{'label': 'X', 'data': ['Jan': 1.366478, 'Feb': -0.061575]}, ... ]
```

I know the basic pandas `.to_json()` may not work here. Probably a combination of list comprehension, lambda function etc. can work here?

The closest I could think of is :

```
dict = {k: df[k].to_dict() for k in df.index.levels[0]}
```

This produce `{'X': {'Feb': -0.06157474257929787, 'Jan': 1.366478487212244},'Y': ...}`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Got a bit more close to solution and probably this is the correct JSON that we can get.

After the previous step of converting to the dictionary need to add these code :

`list[]
for k,v in dict.items():
   dict = {'labell': k, 'data':v}
    list.append(dict)
final_dict = {'data': list}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution I found is below piece of code (Assuming group_data holds the already grouped by data on a DataFrame).

```
group_dict = {k: group_data[k].to_dict() for k in group_data.index.levels[0]}
group_list = []
for k, v in group_dict.items():
    dict = {'label': k, 'data': v}
    group_list.append(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'data':[{'label': 'X', 'data': ['Jan': 1.366478, 'Feb': -0.061575]}, ... ]
```

**This is an invalid json. The inner list doesn't make sense**

Comment: I would have posted this as a comment, rather than as an answer.

Comment: Agree to both @xverges @NiteshK

probably one of these are a valid format closest to what I originally posted. What do you think?

Valid Format #1
`'data':[{'label': 'X', 'data': [1.366478, -0.061575]}, ... ]`

Valid Format #2
`'data':[{'label': 'X', 'data': {'Jan': 1.366478, 'Feb': -0.061575}}, ... ]`

Comment: @AnupamPanda both are valid formats, however Valid Format #2 looks like the corrected version of your initial post